# Replace values from column with another column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables with the following structures:

```
tab1:
| ID | Name  | Col1 |
|----|-------|------|
| 1  | Peter | Null |
| 2  | Lisa  | Null |
| 3  | Eddy  | Null |

tab2:
| ID | Col1 |
|----|------|
| 1  | Abc  |
| 1  | Def  |
| 2  | Ghi  |
```

I want to join these tables in such a way, that all values of `col1` from `tab2` appear in `col1` of `tab1`. So `col1` should just be replaced:

```
| ID | Name  | Col1 |
|----|-------|------|
| 1  | Peter | Abc  |
| 1  | Peter | Def  |
| 2  | Lisa  | Ghi  |
```

It works with `right join`:

```
SELECT tab1.id, name, tab2.col1 FROM tab1 right Join tab2 On tab1.id=tab2.id
```

But here I specified that I only want `col1` from `tab2` to appear, not from `tab1`. In the actual case there are a lot of more columns and I don't want to specify each of them.

So is there a more generic way of replacing the columns of `tab1` with the appropriate columns of `tab2`?

Comment: Just a tip, most people find `left join` much easier to understand than `right join`. Switching to `tab2 left join tab1` would make the code easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Specify each of your columns.

Comment: @Strawberry: That's what I'm trying to avoid. The query should be generic, so the user just needs to specify the first table (in this case `tab1`, but it also could be any other table), whereas `tab2` never changes.

Comment: If there are columns with same name in tables you join, then you MUST explicitly specify table name for such columns or you will get "Ambigous column name" error otherwise.

Comment: Are you trying to save user time or yourself typing time?  You could use `coalesce(tab1.col1, tab2.col1) as col1`... to return the first non-null value this way if col1 has data it will use it otherwise it will use the tab.col you sepcify.

Comment: @xQbert: Usertime. There is an option in the frontend where the user can just chose a table to load data from.

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design. That said, you can alias the columns you DO know about (x.col AS x_col) and then add `y.*` for the columns you DON'T know about. It's NOT what I'd do however.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running

```
SELECT tab1.ID, tab1.Name, tab2.* FROM tab1, tab2 WHERE tab1.ID=tab2.ID;
```

That should do it

Comment: How does the result differ from my result? In this case I also need to specify `tab2.col1`.

Comment: The result doesn't differ. Didn't you want the same?

Comment: I want the same, but without explicitly specifying `tab2.col1`.

Answer (score 0):

Using an inline view you can return just name and ID from tab1 and then join to table 2, and you wouldn't have to alias the columsn then. as they would not be in the generated T1...

```
Select T1.*, T2.* from tab2 t2
LEFT JOIN (Select ID, Name from tab1) T1
 on T1.ID = T2.ID

Select * from tab2 t2
RIGHT JOIN (Select ID, Name from tab1) T1
 on T1.ID = T2.ID
```